# How to find overall running time?

Tags: c

How to find overall running time of the following code snippet ?

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        for (k = 1; k < n; k = k * 2)
            printf("Test")

for (i = 0; i < n ^ 2; i++)
    for (j = 1; j < n; j = j * 2)
        printf("Test")
```

Comment: Are you sure about the `n^2`? Perhaps `n*n`? I generally use `clock()` to make a time stamp before and after the code to be tested. If the execution time is too short to be meaningful, I put the code to be tested inside another loop.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop in both code fragments is the same: it prints `Test` **log2(n)** times.

This inner loops is executed **n * (n + 1) / 2** times in the first case.

Assuming your notation `n ^ 2` really means `n * n`, the inner loop executes **n * n** in the second case.

In both cases the time complexity is the same: **O(n<sup>2</sup>.log(n))**.

The running time may be proportional to the number of iterations, which is `n * (n + 1) / 2 * log2(n)` for the first case and `n * n * log2(n)` for the second, where `log2(n)` is the integer log in base 2, ie: the position of the most significant bit in `n`.

In practice, you should measure running times with `clock()` or `gettimeofday()` on your the target system.

Answer (score 0):

How to find overall running time of the following code snippet ?

```c
     for(j=0;j<n;j++)             //executing this n times
          for(k=1;k<n;k=k*2)      // executing this log(n) times * n times from above
                 printf("Test")
 for(i=0;i<n*n;i++)               //executing this n*n times
        for(j=1;j<n;j=j*2)        //excecting this log(n) times * n * n
                 printf("Test")
```

So this result in n*log(n) + n^2* log(n)

If you ment timing it then put a `clock()` at the start of your programm and 1 at the end and substract the result then print it out

Answer (score 0):

Set a clock at the beginning and at the end of the program and print the difference between both values.

Assume the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    clock_t begin = clock();

    // program here

    clock_t end = clock();
    double spent = (double) (end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("%lf\n", spent); // to get the total execution time
}
```